# Find conflicts between iCal events using python

Tags: python, icalendar

I have two sets of iCal events and I am trying to find the time conflicts between them. Events in both sets have recurring rules.

I do not know of a good strategy of finding the conflicts. The only strategy I have(which is crazy) is to expand the recurrence of each set of events and compare the events one by one to see if there is a conflict. This does not seems right.

Is there some function, or 3rd party library or simple strategy that will do this?

Thanks

Comment: It may be crazy, but I'm pretty sure iCal specifies that you're supposed to process recurrence rules as if they were expanded into the complete recurrence set, so at least this way guarantees that you're following the standard. :)

Comment: Anyway, you might want to look at how iCal4j does it. It's in Java, but it's the most complete iCal library I've used in any language. Also, what do you mean by "compare the events one by one"? If you want O(N+M) time and dead-simple code, just convert the recurrence sets into sets rather than lists, and use the `intersect` method (or `&` operator). If you want O(N+M) time _and_ O(1) space at the cost of slightly more complicated code, just use the same kind of staggered iteration you'd use for any sorted iterables (since you can easily generate the dates in sorted order).

Answer (score 0):

Either way you have to expand the events of the whole calendar I think.  You have to take into account:

- VEVENTS that are modifications (SEQUENCE NO etc) to an instance of a
  recurring event and
- exceptions (EXDATES) to the recurring instance
- possible daylight saving changes during a recurring event defined in a different timezone. a 8am becomes 9am halfway through etc or
- floating dates that stay in local timezone (8 am stays 8am even after daylight saving change) while the event you are comparing may not be floating